# Selecting the amount of users that have no 'thing' assigned to it

Tags: sql

I have a simplified table that shows my problem

Name                   Animal

Bill                     Dog

Bill                           Cat

Bill                           Fish

John                 Cat

John              Fish

Sara                   Dog

Sara                       Cat

Mark                       Fish

I want the number of people that have no dog. I tried this query.

```
select count(distinct Name) from Table
where Animal <> 'Dog'
```

But it returns 4 and not the expected 2. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Use `not exists` :

```
select count(distinct t.name) as counts
from table t
where not exists (select 1 from table where name = t.name and animal = 'Dog');
```

For your current query you are filtering single record based on `animal` name which would not produced desired result as it should be along with `name` column.

Answer (score 1):

Your query returned the count of names that have any animal other than dog.

```
select distinct name
from table t1
where not exists
(
    select 1 from table t2 where t1.name=t2.name and t2.Animal='Dog'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

your where condition "Animal <> 'dog'" is filtering the rows not the names.

So try the below query

```
Select count(distinct Name) from Table where name not in (
select Name from Table  where Animal = 'Dog')
```